# Passing a setState function as a prop is giving me error "Not a Function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

can someone please help me to figure out the mistake?
I'm trying to pass setInput from parent to child component, but somehow it is giving me error.
If I have all the code code in the same component it seems to work fine, but when I split it I get an error

ERROR
setInput is not a function
TypeError: setInput is not a function

````
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState();

  const getMovies = (input) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${input}`)

      .then((res) => {
        console.log("INPUT22", input);
        console.log(res.data, "hello");
        let resp = res.data;
        setCurrentData(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input !== "") {
      getMovies(input);
      console.log("MOVIES", currentData);
    }
  };
  console.log("INPUT", input);
  console.log("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchPage input={input} setInput={setInput} handleClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const SearchBar = ({ input, setInput, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="search__bar">
        <form>
          <input
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="search__input"
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />

          <button type="submit" className="submit__btn" onClick={handleClick}>
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;```
````

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: You used SearchPage instead of SearchBar, was that intentional?

Comment: OMG! that was not intentional! what a silly mistake! Thank you very much!